# snscrape does not give media that I recognize using medium.fullUrl

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I'm trying to build something that will archive part of a user's account using snscraper, however when trying to archive the images that they have sent, The images instead just appear to be random images that that user has never tweeted.

```py
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter

@app.route('/archive', methods=['POST'])
def archive():
    username = request.form["username"]

    try:
        scraper = sntwitter.TwitterUserScraper(username)
        scraper._get_entity()
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid user!")
        return render_template('invalid-user.html')

    print(f"Archiving user: {username}")

    tweet_data = []
    for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterUserScraper('textfiles').get_items():
        if tweet.media:
            for medium in tweet.media:
                if isinstance(medium, sntwitter.Photo):
                    print(medium.previewUrl)
        
        tweet_data.append(tweet)
```